# How to make request by Octokit client

Tags: ruby, api, octokit

I'm using token to access github api by Octokit client.

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: TOKEN)
```

It seems that is ok:

```
client.rate_limit
=> #<struct Octokit::RateLimit
 limit=5000,
 remaining=4998,
 resets_at=2013-11-25 03:38:41 +0200,
 resets_in=3533>
```

So now I want to get some info

```
repo = client.repo 'rails/rails'
repo.rels[:events]
repo.rels[:events].get.data
```

But when I'm getting next page

```
repo.rels[:events].get[:next]
```

I'm hitting the rate limit in 60 requests per hour.

It seems that next requests are not authorized by token.

How to make all request be authorized by token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your token has been expired or your `client` variable lost scope.

Create a initializers/octokit.rb with authentication:

```
Octokit.configure do |c|
  c.client_id = ENV['GITHUB_ID']
  c.client_secret = ENV['GITHUB_SECRET']
end
```

I chose to do by id and secret.

And make your requests with:

```
repo = Octokit.repo 'rails/rails'
```

After create the initializer, you can test in `rails c`:

```
> Octokit.rate_limit
 => #<struct Octokit::RateLimit limit=5000, remaining=4927, resets_at=2016-04-22 12:24:52 -0300, resets_in=2102>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Octokit documentation](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb):

> Note: While Octokit auto pagination will set the page size to the
>   maximum 100, and seek to not overstep your rate limit, you probably
>   want to use a custom pattern for traversing large lists.

Comment: The rate limit for application that are authorized by token is 5000 requests per hour, I just want use this limit.